To speak like my role model
https://youtu.be/9CrGRaA7jr0?feature=shared
This is a link for a youtube video of General Sam Manekshaw's speech on “Leadership”.
General Manekshaw has been my role model since I first got to know about him. Only recently, when I decided to join the Indian Army as an officer, I thought I should improve myself or make a Manekshaw out of me.
The problem is I do not know what to improve on (please do tell), how to be like those witty and charismatic British officers that I have seen in many movies of the 1914-18 and 1939-45 world?
So, I thought to start with 'speaking like Sam as he did in the video'. Things I observed :
His vocabulary was vibrant and his thoughts were inspiring, his pronunciation was posh (I am assuming that was because his job required him to talk to people from overseas), his talk was engaging and had occasional hints of humor.
How do learn to talk like him ? (I understand that this skill is not purely linguistic and other attributes are required, well then how do I improve up on those attributes?)

Your question is much too broad for this site, which accepts specific questions of usage and grammar. The close votes are in response to its broadness.

Generally no: be yourself. Learn to be a better you, not someone else.

... and Manekshaw was half a century ago. Learn to be a man of your time. not a past time.

"My Fair Lady" is a fantasy. There's no magic road to learning to speak well, it comes from years of experience.

It sounds like you are confused between being an officer and acting like one. You may perhaps be intoxicated by what you think is the 'glamour' of the role. Those films did not show the reality of war, the mangled corpses, the sudden death, the fear, etc.

My father was an officer in the Royal Air Force during World War II, and his account of life was not very romantic. Men killed because of stupid, lazy, or cowardly leaders.

@MichaelHarvey , I do not have a firsthand experience of wars but I do realise that wars are not glamourous and result in pointless deaths, almost all of the movies that I have seen are “anti-war”. Therefore it is important that those who want to be officers must improve themselves in all sorts of ways so that that horrors of world wars are not repeated. is what I actually think...
